# objective c Drag And Drop IN OS X Sierra 10.12

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, drag-and-drop, macos-sierra, nstabview

In OS X sierra 10.12 Drag and drop  is not working properly with NSTabView....
Drag and drop seems to only work in label of TabView not the entire tab ..you can see in the following project sample...[download Code](https://www.dropbox.com/s/3zqhgbxzxegaid7/Drag_DropInOsXSierra.zip?dl=0)
OR here is code:-I have created a subClass **AppMainTabSet** OF NSTabView and use this class as a custom class of  TabView In Interface Builder.....

```
 #import "AppMainTabSet.h"

@implementation AppMainTabSet


- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder
{
    /*------------------------------------------------------
     Init method called for Interface Builder objects
     --------------------------------------------------------*/
    self=[super initWithCoder:coder];
    if ( self ) {



    }
    return self;
}

- (void)awakeFromNib{

       [self registerForDraggedTypes:[NSArray arrayWithObject:NSFilenamesPboardType]];

    }


-(NSDragOperation) draggingEntered:(id < NSDraggingInfo >)sender
{
    NSLog(@"Hello Hello....draggingEntered");
    return NSDragOperationGeneric;
}




- (void)draggingExited:(id <NSDraggingInfo>)sender {
     NSLog(@"**** draggingExited*****");

}

- (BOOL) prepareForDragOperation:(id <NSDraggingInfo>)sender {
     NSLog(@"Hello Hello....prepareForDragOperation");
    return YES;
}



- (BOOL)performDragOperation:(id <NSDraggingInfo>)sender
{

    NSLog(@"Hello Hello....performDragOperation");

    return YES;
}

- (void)concludeDragOperation:(id <NSDraggingInfo>)sender {
   NSLog(@"Hello Hello....concludeDragOperation");

    [[NSCursor arrowCursor] push];
    [self setNeedsDisplay:YES];
}

- (BOOL) processNSDraggingInfo:(id <NSDraggingInfo>)sender {


   NSLog(@"Hello Hello....processNSDraggingInfo");

    return YES;
}
```

Comment: No, we are not going to see inside a project on dropbox. You need to isolate and share here the code section that performs the D&D.

Comment: I shared my Code ...you can please See ...again in the question

Comment: Did it work in (previous) versions of OS X?

Comment: Yes it is working even now till 10.11.6 but as soon as we upgraded one of system to Sierra beta it is not working. Though Sierra is out on 20th Sept so may be Apple has fixed it. Here is another lead to it https://forums.balsamiq.com/t/cannot-drag-and-drop-elements-macos-sierra/2868/29. (@Shiv is my teammate so I am just updating it on behalf of him).

Comment: It is still same after upgrading to 10.12 final release on 20th Sept.

Comment: it is still same after upgrading macOS sierra 10.12.1 Beta (16B2548a)